# How do I programmatically extract values from DatePicker/TimePicker Spinners in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, timepicker, android-datepicker

I originally followed the tutorial on [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), but since I plan on having 2 of each on the page, I figured it'd be a bit more elegant to pull the values from the pickers. I first used the onClick methods in the XML; however, now, I am attempting to pull the values once a button (btn_schedule_adventure) is pressed. I get an error when I try and set the DateView

```
DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_start_date);
```

The code I have below throws an error. How do I:
1-Pull the values out of the date/time pickers (bypassing the error below)
2-While maintaining the default times/dates

Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.DatePicker
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.scarr025.zwilio.AdventureSetUp$1.onClick(AdventureSetUp.java:40)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Method

```
public class AdventureSetUp extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remove title bar
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Log.d("$$LOGCHECK$$", "In onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adventure_set_up); 

    Button btnScheduleAdventure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_schedule_adventure);
    btnScheduleAdventure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //perform your action here
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get adventure title
            EditText btnScheduleAdventure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adventure_title);
            String adventureTitle = btnScheduleAdventure.getText().toString();
            // Get adventure start date
            DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_start_date);
            int startDay = startDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int startMonth = startDatePicker.getMonth();
            int startYear = startDatePicker.getYear();      

            Log.d("$$LOGCHECK$$", "Clicked Schedule Adventure");
            Log.d("$$LOGCHECK$$", "Title: " + adventureTitle);
            Log.d("$$LOGCHECK$$", "Start Date: " + startMonth + "-" + startDay + "-" + startYear);


            Intent newIntent = new Intent();

        }
    });
}
```

Date/Time Picker Code (from tutorial)

```
//---------------Date/Time Picker Methods-------------------------------------
// Date Picker
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        Log.d("$$LOGCHECK$$", "Date Picked--Year:" + year + " Month: " + month + " Day: " + day);
    }
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

// Time Picker
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AdventureSetUp" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/adventure_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_adventure_title"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/picker_start_date"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_adventure_start_date" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_adventure_start_time" 
    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" />


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/picker_end_date"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_adventure_end_date" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_adventure_end_time" 
    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_schedule_adventure"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_schedule_adventure" 
    android:onClick="scheduleAdventure" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clearly stated here:

```
05-26 04:27:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.DatePicker
```

Because you are retrieving this button:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/picker_start_date"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_adventure_end_date" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
```

as a DatePicker here:

```
DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_start_date);
```

So change this:

```
DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_start_date);
```

by:

```
Button startDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picker_start_date);
```

Comment: I know that, thanks. I am trying to pull the values out of a date/time picker fragment. Why would change it to a button? I can't pull the values out of a button...

Comment: What he is saying is your thrown exception was an invalid cast (DatePicker.class cannot cast to Button.class) so by changing the object of "statDatePicker" from the class of "DatePicker" to the class "Button" it should be a valid cast (or using the right class).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to pull the values.

There is a `onDateSet` method which will be called automatically when you click the **Set** button in the DatePickerDialog.

Can you see this line in you `Logcat` when you click on Set in DatePickerDialog.

```
Date Picked--Year:" + year + " Month: " + month + " Day: " + day
```

Comment: yes, however, I need to save 2 datepicker values. Is it possible to pull the value of these datepicker fragments after they've been assigned? (not via a onClick method)